# Firestore data appending, not updating recycler view

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

In android studio, using Java and firestore, I am trying to fill a recycler view with data in the store. It needs to create 1 object for each, this object has buttons and some text which needs to be updated using a snapshot function.
The problem is that it currently populates a list named gsmModels, This list's data is then used to populate the desired fields.
Problem is, it appends to the view, rather than updating, or overwriting the views.

Please note, me being here is a last resort, and chatGPT is basically useless with this specific question -> It just keeps running me in circles.

The device id's gets drawn from a _users entry on the server, this data i then use to populate a list named "keysList", this keys list is then responsible for holding all the device ids which I need to target and append to the recycler view.
Again, problem is that it appends the data, growing the list constantly, instead of overwriting the data or updating it.
I can't add stopListener functions, because I need this app to constantly listen for changes.
Please let me know if there is a small change I can make to the code to make it work, if not, what should I do to re write if needed.

Here is my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends DrawerBaseActivity implements GetBaseUnits.BaseUnitsCallback {
    // Array List that will hold all the gsmModels
    List<ConnectedGsmModel> gsmModels = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    GsmModelAdapter adapter;

    // set up base units class
    GetBaseUnits getBaseUnits = new GetBaseUnits();

    // Declare the keysList
    List<String> keysList;

    // The code below references the menu
    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding;
    // The code above references the menu

    // Set Up okhttp
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    // Get CollectionReference
    // serialString needs to be a loop iterator that assigns the values to docRef
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    // Set up FirebaseAuth
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String currentUserId = currentUser.getUid();

    // Get a document
    DocumentReference userDevicesDoc = db.collection("_userDevices").document(currentUserId);

    // Other declarations
    TextView base_title;
    TextView last_status;
    TextView current_armed_status;
    String menu_user_name;
    Button panic_btn, arrow_right_btn, arm_btn, disarm_btn;
    Map<String, Object> bigObject = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> userDevices = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // The code below references the menu
        activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(activityMainBinding.getRoot());
        allocateActivityTitle("Dashboard");
        // The code above references the menu

        // This is all recycler view related
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.gsmRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        base_title = findViewById(R.id.base_title);
        last_status = findViewById(R.id.last_status);
        panic_btn = findViewById(R.id.panic_btn);
        arrow_right_btn = findViewById(R.id.arrow_right_btn);
        arm_btn = findViewById(R.id.arm_btn);
        disarm_btn = findViewById(R.id.disarm_btn);
        current_armed_status = findViewById(R.id.current_armed_status); // boolean value

        getBaseUnits.getBaseUnits(this);

        // Initialize the gsmModels list with your data
//        gsmModels = (ArrayList<ConnectedGsmModel>) DataRepository.getInstance().getConnectedGsmModels();

        // Create an instance of your custom adapter, passing the gsmModels list
        adapter = new GsmModelAdapter(gsmModels, bigObject);

        // Set the adapter to the RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } // end of the oncreate method

    public void importKeysArrayList() {
        getBaseUnits.getBaseUnits(this);
    }

    public void onBaseUnitsReceived(List<String> keysArrayList) {
        // Assign keysArrayList to keysList
        keysList = keysArrayList;

        for(String key : keysList ) {
            String serialString = key;

            System.out.println("Current Serial Loop: " + serialString);
            // call the snapshotFunction after keysList is assigned
            snapshotFunction(serialString);
        } // end of for loop
    }

    // snapshotFunction that retrieves all data from Firestore and stores it in a map
    public void snapshotFunction(String serialString) {
        gsmModels.clear();
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection(serialString).document("system");
        docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen Failed: ", error);
                }
                if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                    // Store the retrieved data in the bigObject map
                    bigObject = snapshot.getData();

                    Log.w(TAG, String.valueOf(bigObject), null);

                    // Create a new gsmModels list for this iteration
//                    ArrayList<ConnectedGsmModel> gsmModels = new ArrayList<>();

                    // Add the ConnectedGsmModel to the gsmModels list
                    gsmModels.add(new ConnectedGsmModel(
                            bigObject.get("name") != null ? bigObject.get("name").toString() : "",
                            bigObject.get("lstate") != null ? bigObject.get("lstate").toString() : "",
                            bigObject.get("armed") != null ? bigObject.get("armed").toString() : ""
                    ));

                    // Update the gsmModels list in the adapter
                    adapter.setGsmModels(gsmModels);

                    System.out.println("Current gsmModel size: " + gsmModels.size());

                    // Notify the adapter that the data has changed
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    // Array List that holds the connected GSM Serials
                    Log.d(TAG, "Keys Array List: " + keysList);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "This is not going too well.", null);
                    Log.w(TAG, "Value of Big Object: " + String.valueOf(bigObject), null);
                }
            }
        });
    } // end of snapshot function
    // This one works, but it keeps appending to gsmModels upon each update
}
```

This is my adapter code:

```
package com.example.kwebeamsapp2;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsmModelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GsmModelAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<ConnectedGsmModel> gsmModels;

    public GsmModelAdapter(List<ConnectedGsmModel> gsmModels, Map<String, Object> bigObject) {
        this.gsmModels = gsmModels;
    }

    // Method to update the gsmModels list
    public void setGsmModels(List<ConnectedGsmModel> gsmModels) {
        this.gsmModels = gsmModels;
    }

    // Create ViewHolder instances
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // Bind data to ViewHolder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ConnectedGsmModel model = gsmModels.get(position);
        // Bind the data from the model to the views in the ViewHolder
        holder.bind(model);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return gsmModels.size();
    }

    // ViewHolder class
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView base_title;
        private TextView last_status;
        private TextView current_armed_status;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            base_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.base_title);
            last_status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_status);
            current_armed_status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.current_armed_status);
        }

        public void bind(ConnectedGsmModel model) {
            base_title.setText(model.getBase_title());
            last_status.setText(model.getLast_status());
            current_armed_status.setText(model.getCurrent_armed_status());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the problem starts here:

```
public void snapshotFunction(String serialString) {
    gsmModels.clear();
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection(serialString).document("system");
    docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            ...
```

You're calling `gsmModels.clear();` **outside** of the `onEvent` method. So the first time you get data from the database, you're starting with an empty list - but every time you receive updates, you're adding them to the list that you already populated.

To fix this, clear the list inside `onEvent`, right before you add data to it:

```
public void snapshotFunction(String serialString) {
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection(serialString).document("system");
    docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            gsmModels.clear(); // 
            ...
```

Comment: I tried this before, and it did not work. (I just tried it again to remember what exactly happens if I do it that way). What it does then is, it only gives me the last object, as opposed to all 5. Then, when it refreshes, it gives me the first, then on refresh, the 2nd, then on refresh, the 3rd... and so on. Note where I write System.out.println("Current gsmModel size: " + gsmModels.size());, that returns 1, instead of 5. Which is the true lengh.

Comment: OK. In that you'll need to determine the right spot to clear the list. It could be that this needs to happen in `onBaseUnitsReceived`, but I don't see when that it called.

Comment: I tried moving it into the onBaseUnitsReceived, but the appending is still an issue.
Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to comment the entire document.
Code in a File called GetBaseUnits.java :
```
Map<String, Object> arr = document.getData();
callback.onBaseUnitsReceived(keysArrayList);
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : arr.entrySet()) {
String key = entry.getKey();
Object value = entry.getValue();
if(key.equals("1")) {
continue;
} else {
Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " and the Value: " + value);
keysArrayList.add(key);
}
} 

callback.onBaseUnitsReceived(keysArrayList);

Comment: Sorry for the insane formatting, but stackoverflow.